# Calculating the voltage difference between a switching pin out and a constant Vout

Tags: voltage

Sorry to trouble you all with a similar question. But this is a different question altogether regarding calculation of voltage difference.
I am using NCV3063 IC.

According to my design of the boost converter in my board, I am measuring the values of pin1 and pin2 in multimeter and scope respectively. This is a reference board.

For Vin(Vcc) of 16V, The voltage at pin1(SWC) of the IC is 5.05V as measured in DMM.

1. Pin2 (SWE), I am measuring in scope, I am getting a peak-peak of some 15.8V with 30.6% duty and max amplitude of 13.8V.
2. Now, Vswce=difference between the pins 1 and 2.

How to calculate the voltage difference between (1) and(2)?

Or in general, how to calculate the voltage difference between a switching Vout pin (here, pin2) and a constant Vout pin (here, pin1).

Please help

Thanks

Comment: You should include the **schematic** of your boost converter.

Comment: As pointed out in comments provide a **schematic** this can probably be taken from the IC data sheet or application note.  Also provide links to the data sheet and if applicable application note.

Answer (score 0):

From Spec

> VSWCE(DROP) Darlington Switch Collector to
>   Emitter Voltage Drop
>   (**ISW = 1.0 A,** Pin 2 to GND,
>   TJ = 25°C)
>   **1.0Vtyp 1.3 Vmax**
>   Note 7. Low duty cycle pulse techniques are used during test to maintain junction temperature as close to ambient temperature as possible

This implies Rce= 300 mohms + 0.8V of Vbe or using linear regression,
 **Vce= 0.8 + Ic * 0.3Ω**

[image]